# SharePoint 2003: List all checked-out documents

Tags: list, check-out, 2003

I'm in a process where I'm copying documents from a SharePoint 2003-site to a new 2007 site. The problem is that documents that are checked out on the 2003-site are not copied in their newest version (the checked out version).

We have many folders and documents and hence wonder: is there an easy way (preferably using the web user interface) to list all documents in a document library that are checked out to somebody?

Please let me know if you know how this can be done, or if you can point me to a previous post that can help me.

Answer (score 4):

NO-Code: Try building a view that ignores Folders and filters out by the CheckOut To column not being NULL - this means actually the document is checkout.

Comment: Hi, this worked out well for me although I had to export to excel and filter on checked out != (blanks) in excel as there was no option in SharePoint view to filter on checked out column. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also used the NO-Code (New View) suggestion, and it worked great for me. I used a filter of >= a, which seemed to work and bring back all the checked out files. Using the >=a trick avoided the Export to Excel step.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of checked out items from **Content and Structure reports** from 2007 and 2010. Visit [this blog](http://arabic2000.com/blog/index.php/archives/364) or [this msdn post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2006/11/15/report-rapport.aspx) on the steps to accomplish this.

This is an out of the box feature which should be available if you have publishing feature enabled in your site. I am not quite sure about SharePoint 2003 site though. You might have to try it out.

Basically the report uses the below CAML query to retrieve all the documents that are checked out -

`<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" LookupId="TRUE"/></IsNotNull></Where>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I tried C. Marius' method first as this seemed easier and this turned out to work well, so did not try your method.